# Are all thunderbolt 3 ports 40Gb/s?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, thunderbolt

Everywhere that I read about the specs of thunderbolt 3 says it is 40gb/s. However, some manufacturers and vendors advertise thunderbolt 3 with 20gb/s. Is this a typo?

https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G752VY/

https://www.pbtech.co.nz/index.php?z=p&p=NBKASU720916&name=ASUS-G752VT-GC053T-17.3-FHD---Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ

Would 20gb/s be much of a disadvantage if using a high-powered external GPU?

Comment: There are different revision of Thunderbolt

Comment: If a laptop advertises Thundebolt support, and mentions 20 GB/sec bandwidth, then the port is Thunderbolt 2 not Thunderbolt 3 or The ASUS page clearly has a mistake in it, since USB 3.1 Type C, must mean Thunderbolt 3  **Thunderbolt 2 and Thunderbolt 3 are also not interchangeable with one another**

Comment: This is because they don't have a separate thunderbolt 3 port, instead, they're using a new USB 3.1 Type-C port which combines USB 3.1 Type-C and Thunderbolt 3 technologies. This new technology provides users to use both "USB 3.1 Type-C and Thunderbolt" in one port. As of Thunderbolt 3, you'll be using a passive Thunderbolt cable, which will reduce the speed rate to half of the full Thunderbolt speed. Also, you can use A USB 3.1 Type-C cable with the same port if you want to use it as a USB.